# Javascript alert is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<html>

<body>

  <p>Enter names in the fields, then click "Submit" to submit the form:</p>


  <form name="form">

    <input type="text" id="birthDate">

    <br> Current Date

    <br>

    <input type="text" id="currentDate">

    <br>

    <br>

    <br>

    <a id="Submit_Button" onclick="test();" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Submit">Submit</a>

  </form>
  <script>
    function test() {


      var birthDate = document.getElementById("birthDate");

      var currentDate = document.getElementById("currentDate");




      var ageDate = birthDate.value - currentDate.value;


      function ageD(ageDate) {
        if (ageDate < 1) {
          return function calculate(y) {
            Math.abs(ageDate) = y
          }
        } else {
          return function calculate(y) {
            ageDate = y
          }
        }
      }
      var ageDale = ageD();
      var x = ageDale(ageDate);



      alert(x)
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I can't seem to fix this. I keep getting undefined for x, its probably something simple, but i appreciate the help.

It might have something to do with my functions, because i didnt really know what i was doing when i set them up.

Comment: `not working` is not a very good description of a problem, aren't you getting any alerts at all, or is it just alerting `undefined` ?

Comment: i just get the alert saying defined, and nothing is wrong on the console

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the `calculate` functions

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand your logic, but functions that are being returned by `ageD` should in turn return some value, since you clearly expect them to produce something:

```
var x = ageDale(ageDate);
```

At the moment those `calculate` functions are not returning anything, so `x` is `undefined`. Looks like you want something like this:

```
function ageD(ageDate) {
    if (ageDate < 1) {
        return function calculate(y) {
            return Math.abs(ageDate);
        }
    } else {
        return function calculate(y) {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function AgeDale isn't defined. You need to call a function, not a variable called ageDale

Comment: `var ageDale = ageD();` while named interestingly, is assigned the returned value of calling `ageD` which is a function. This allows `ageDale(ageDate);` to be used because you are calling the returned function. There is nothing wrong with that aspect of the code above. The problem, as pointed out by others, is that the returned function doesn't return a value, and as a result undefined is alerted.

Answer (score 0):

function `ageD()` expects one parameter and you are not passing anything, so the function is always returning the `else` statement.

You are asigning to `x` variable the return of that function, but it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the user's age, you could have them enter a year such as 1990 and 2014 and this:

```
function test() {
  var birthDate = document.getElementById("birthDate");
  var currentDate = document.getElementById("currentDate");
  var ageDate =  currentDate.value - birthDate.value;
  function ageD(ageDate) {
    if (ageDate < 1) {
      return function calculate(y) {
        Math.abs(ageDate) = y
      }
    } else {
      return ageDate
    }
  }
  var ageDale = ageD();
  var x = ageDate;
  alert(x)
}
```

Otherwise, if you want them to enter dates like dd/mm/yyyy you will have to something different.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
  // convert the input into intiger
  var birthDate = parseInt(document.getElementById("birthDate").value, 10);
  var currentDate = parseInt(document.getElementById("currentDate").value, 10);
  var ageDate = birthDate - currentDate;

  function ageD(ageDate) {
    return Math.abs(ageDate);
  }
  var x = ageD(ageDate);
  alert(x);
}
```